# how to get form input fields value in an array in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.x

I am new to cakephp. Thanks all in advance. I am using `Cakephp2.8.5` version. I have a form with input fields and a submit button. When I am submitting a form, the input fields should pass through the array and should store in a variable called `$totalData` and I want to store the array variable `$totalData` in a session variable in `cakephp`. I have written code in the Userscontroller's `cartData` function. Please help me find out how to declare an array and store it in a  session variable in cakephp.
My `index.ctp` page:

```
    <form  method="post" action="<?php echo $this->webroot ?>users/cartData?>""> 
   <table><thead>
          <th>Exam Name</th>
          <th>Venue Name</th>
          <th>Date of Exam</th>

          <th>Price / Course</th>  
          <th>Number of Exams</th>            
          <th>Add to Cart</th> 
         </thead>
         <tbody>
          <tr>      
             <td>
                <select name="course">   
                  <option value="">--Select--</option>            
                  <option value="ITIL Foundation">ITIL Foundation</option>
                  <option value="PMP">PMP</option>
                  <option value="Prince 2 Foundation">Prince 2 Foundation</option>
                </select>           
             </td>    
              <td><input type="text" name="venue" id="venue"></td>        
              <td><input type="text" name="Userdate" id="Userdate" ></td>   

              <td><input type="text" name="txtprice" id="Userdate" ></td>
              <td>
                <select name="num_exams">   
                  <option value="">--Select--</option>            
                  <option value="1">1</option>
                  <option value="2">2</option>
                  <option value="3">3</option>
                </select>           
             </td>
             <td><input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" value="Submit"></td>

         </tr></tbody>

      </table>

My `UsersController.php` page :

<?php
App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');
class UsersController extends AppController
{   

  public function cartData()
  {

    if($this->request->is('post')|| $this->request->is('put'))
    { 
       $totalData = array(

        'exam' => $this->Form->input('course'),
        'venue' => $this->Form->input('venue'),
        'date' => $this->Form->input('Userdate'),
        'price' => $this->Form->input('txtprice'),
        'orders' => $this->Form->input('num_exams')

    );

// I have a confusion how to store array values in session variable

     $_SESSION['total_data'][] = $totalData; 



    }


  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Always make the best effort to use the framework in all that's possible. Some very specific cases are a problem to use the Helpers on, but otherwise, always try and use them.

```
<?php
$courseOptions = array(
    'ITIL Foundation' => 'ITIL Foundation', 
    'PMP' => 'PMP',
    'Prince 2 Foundation' => 'Prince 2 Foundation'
); 
$examOptions = array(1,2,3); 
?>
<?=$this->Form->create('User', array('action' => 'cartData'))?>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Exam Name</th>
            <th>Venue Name</th>
            <th>Date of Exam</th>
            <th>Price / Course</th>  
            <th>Number of Exams</th>            
            <th>Add to Cart</th> 
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>      
            <td>
                <?=$this->Form->input('course', array('options' => $courseOptions)?>
            </td>
            <td><?=$this->Form->input('venue')?></td>
            <td><?=$this->Form->input('userdate')?></td>
            <td><?=$this->Form->input('txtprice')?></td>
            <td><?=$this->Form->input('num_exams', array('options' => $examOptions)); ?></td>
            <td><?=$this->Form->submit('Submit')?></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<?=$this->Form->end()?>
```

All Form input helpers create an array based on the created form. In this case it generates a data[User][course] for name on each, and UserCourse for id (using first input as example).

On the controller side, you access your the data array on `$this->request->data` which will have that very structure (i.e. `$this->request->data['User']['course']` to access the first input value).

Answer (score 0):

Use the Session component and write your array to the session using:

```
$this->Session->write('cart', $totalData);
```

The Session component is probably already included in your AppController.php, if not add it there (or in your UsersController.php if you will only use it there):

```
    var $components = array('Session');
```

(add 'Session' to any other components already listed)

Comment: I have to pass these session array values in foreach loop to display in view page.How can i do this?

Comment: Why means? I want to display the input fields data in a row below in a seperate table whenever I am submitting the form

Comment: how to pass this session variable in foreach to pass in the view page. I used $this->set('cartDatas',$totalData); When i was accessing in the view page using print_r($cartDatas);  its showing that undefined variable cartDatas

Comment: I used $this->set('cartDatas',$totalData); in the controller

Answer (score 0):

```
$totalData = array(

    'exam' => $this->Form->input('course'),
    'venue' => $this->Form->input('venue'),
    'date' => $this->Form->input('Userdate'),
    'price' => $this->Form->input('txtprice'),
    'orders' => $this->Form->input('num_exams')

);
```

Is this part of your code working? Can you show the debug of $totalData please?

Comment: Iam not sure . I used var_dump(totalData); die();   but its not working. Actually I want to display the input fields data in a row below in a seperate table whenever I am submitting the form like adding to cart

Comment: I think you should use '$totalData = array(

    'exam' => $this->Form->input('course'),
    'venue' => $this->Form->input('venue'),
    'date' => $this->Form->input('Userdate'),
    'price' => $this->Form->input('txtprice'),
    'orders' => $this->Form->input('num_exams')

);'

Comment: I think you should use :'

Comment: I think you should use : 
'$totalData = array(
    'exam' => $this->request->data['course'],
    'venue' => $this->request->data['venue'],
    'date' => $this->request->data['Userdate'],
    'price' => $this->request->data['txtprice'],
    'orders' => $this->request->data['num_exams']
);'
then debug the array.

Comment: How to debug this array.Actually i used var_dump($totalData); die() but no result

Comment: try using debug($totalData); die();

Answer (score 0):

`$this->Form->input()` is a method of the FormHelper, it is intended to be used in the view not controller in order to generate form inputs alongside `$this->Form->create()` and `$this->Form->end()`.

In your controller form inputs are accessed using `$this->request->data['Model']['fieldname']`

You can do something like this in your view

```
<?php 
$courseOptions = array(
    'ITIL Foundation' => 'ITIL Foundation', 
    'PMP' => 'PMP',
    'Prince 2 Foundation' => 'Prince 2 Foundation'
); 

$examOptions = array('1' => '1', '2' => '2', '3' => '3'); 
echo $this->Form->create('User', array('action' => 'cartData')); 
?>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Exam Name</th>
            <th>Venue Name</th>
            <th>Date of Exam</th>
            <th>Price / Course</th>  
            <th>Number of Exams</th>            
            <th>Add to Cart</th> 
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>      
            <td>
                <?php echo $this->Form->input('course', array('options' => $courseOptions)); ?>
            </td>
            <td><?php echo $this->Form->input('venue'); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $this->Form->input('userdate'); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $this->Form->input('txtprice'); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $this->Form->input('num_exams', array('options' => $examOptions)); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $this->Form->submit('Submit'); ?></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

You can then do something like this in your controller

```
<?php
App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');
class UsersController extends AppController
{   
    public function cartData()
    {
        if($this->request->is('post')|| $this->request->is('put'))
        { 
            $totalData = array(
                'exam' => $this->request->data['User']['course'],
                'venue' => $this->request->data['User']['venue'],
                'date' => $this->request->data['User']['userdate'],
                'price' => $this->request->data['User']['txtprice'],
                'orders' => $this->request->data['User']['num_exams']
            );

            $this->Session->write('total_data', $totalData);

            // Alternatively you can do something like this
            $this->Session->write('total_data', $this->request->data['User']);
        }
    }
}
```

You may need to enable the Session component, I strongly advise [reading the blog tutorial](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/blog.html) in the cookbook to get a grasp of these common components / helpers and how post data is accessed